# Only update partial view on page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating charts using Google's chart api. I have a dropdown with customers and when a customer is selected the customer I only want the partial view with my chart to be updated, and not the whole site. Because if the site is refreshed then the dropdown will reset.

This is my code for the dropdown part of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeCustomer() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "Reports/GetReportbyCustomer/",
            data: { customerId: $("#Customers").val() },
            complete: function (result) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="filters">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerId) </td>
            <td colspan="3">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers, Model.Customers, new { @onchange = "changeCustomer()" })</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="content">
    @Html.Partial("TotalReport", Model.printDocuments)
</div>
```

The TotaltReports partial view only contains the build of the chart and the `<div>` for the chart to be viewed in. the only important thing here is I use a `List<PrintDocumentsViewModel>` as model.

When the result is returned the response is html code for the whole page. how would I only refresh my TotaltReport partial view ?

Comment: Then call a method that only returns a partial containing only what you want to update.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  so use return partialview() and then insert the content into the div that is surrounding  this call   @Html.Partial("TotalReport", Model.printDocuments) ?

Comment: I have no idea what you `GetReportbyCustomer()` returns (you have not shown your controller code) but assuming its a partial that your want to update, then in the ajax success callback - `success: function(data) { $('#content').html(data); }`

Answer (score 0):

when you change the dropdown by selstion custome, the `ajax` is called and the data is send to the `GetReportbyCustomer` controller. 
Change `ajax dataType` to `dataType: 'html'` then only html partial or full page cannot loaded.
Then in `GetReportbyCustomer` controller

```
public ActionResult GetReportbyCustomer()
{
    .
    .
    return PartialView("PartialViewPageName", data to page);
}
```

create a partial page in the name of `PartialViewPageName`
Then the html page will be returned to the `ajax sucess` event and load the data to view like

```
 success: function (result) 
 {
     $('#content').html(data);
 }
```

In view

```
<div id="content">
    Your data will be loaded here
</div>
```